# После ajax перезагрузки страницы иконки прилипают наверх блока

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, изображения

Всем привет. Подскажите плиз, почему после (ajax) перезагрузки страницы иконки прилипают вверх кружков? Насколько я понимаю: `line-height` после перезагрузки теряется?

```css
.mad-breadcrumbs {
  margin-top: 11px;
  font-size: .9em;
}
span.table {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 18px;
  width: 440px;
}
.mad-breadcrumbs > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.border {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 14px;
}
.product-category {
  display: block;
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  margin: 4px 0 0 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #979567;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
a {
  color: #979567;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  border: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="mad-breadcrumbs">
  <span class="table">
 <span class="border"><a class="product-category" href="#"><img src="http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/circularicons/16x16/star_green.png"></a></span>
  <div class="vert-hr"></div><span class="border"><a class="product-category" href="#"><img src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/0612/vistabasesoftwareicons/w24h241339252717HelpCircleBlue6.png"></a></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}    
img {
      -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
      border: 0;
      height: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      /*vertical-align: top;*/
    }
```

В конце ошибка. Вы переопределяете vertical-align

Comment: нет, не в этом дело